# How To stop feedItem for status field on Case?

Tags: case, feeditem, chatter-feed

I have enabled feed tracking for Case. But the status field is not set to tracking. But I am still able to see the feedItem on status changes.

Please, let me know if I am missing anything or it can be changed

Answer (score 2):

These objects and fields are tracked by default:

1. Account: Account Name, Account Owner
2. **Case: Case Owner, Priority, Status**
3. Chatter Group: Allow Customers, Description, Group Access,
   Information Body, Information Title, Name, Owner Name
4. Contact: Account Name, Contact Owner, Name
5. Lead: Lead Owner, Lead Status, Name
6. Opportunity: Amount, Close Date, Opportunity Name, Opportunity
   Owner, Stage
7. Topic: Description
8. User: About Me, Address, Email, Manager, Phone, Title

In order to stop, you need to switch off the feed tracking on the object.

Reference:- [Feed Tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_feed_tracking_overview.htm&type=5)

Comment: Is there a way I can overwrite the default behaviour for case status field?

Comment: Also can I stop the feedItem that says "case is created".